# Nodemon crashed and waiting for file to be changed

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const products_routes = require("./routes/products");

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello this is my API");
})

app.use("/api/products", products_routes);

const start = async() => {
    try {
        app.listen(PORT, () => {
            console.log(`${PORT} Yes I am connected`);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

start();
```

This is the app.js file

```
const express = require("express");

const router = express.Router();

const { 
    getAllProducts, 
    getAllProductsTesting 
} = require("../controllers/products");

router.route("/").get(getAllProducts);

router.route("/testing").get(getAllProductsTesting);
```

This is the route.js file

```
const getAllProducts = async (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({ msg: "I am getAllProducts" });
}

const getAllProductsTesting = async (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({ msg: "I am getAllProductsTesting" });
}

module.exports = { 
    getAllProducts, 
    getAllProductsTesting 
};
```

This is the controller.js file

I am expecting that running this code will give me the response as "https://localhost:3000/api/products but it's giving me cannot find get error and now it's giving me nodemon error

Comment: Your app crashed (and probably produced some error output while doing so) and nodemon doesn't restart the process until you change something in your app (because it likely would crash again, and this would lead to a never-ending restart-crash loop). So check the output for more information about the error, and fix that error

Answer (score 0):

In which line are you exporting your `router` from the `route.js` file ? I don't see any export statements in the code you provided and you are importing it in the `app.js` file.